# Issues with cocoapods after upgrading Xcode

Tags: swift, cocoapods, iqkeyboardmanager

Updated my Xcode project and my `IQKeyboardManager` cocoapod was not working. I updated it and now I get this error:

> Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Any help on how to 'rebuild' a cocopod?

Comment: What does "Updated my Xcode project" mean?  You've made changes to your Xcode project?  Or you've updated your Xcode 7 project for Xcode 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rebuild the Cocoapods repo. You need to use the `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES` in your project.